# How to code an ADC for an atmega328p in assembly

Tags: assembly, atmega, adc

I have done a huge amount of research and have found next to nothing in assembly.
My code does not work and I do not understand why, it is supposed to alter the speed at which the lights change colour using the delay loop, I'm very new to assembly and would appreciate any help.

```
    ;
; Labs.asm
;
; Created: 8/14/2016 7:34:43 AM
; Author : Dario
;


; Replace with your application code
    .include "M328PDEF.INC"
    .org 0x000
start:
    ;ddrx controls the if a pin is in/out, if the pins corresponding bit in the ddr is 1 it's an out, if it's 0 its an in
    ldi r16, 0x00 ; set r16 = 0000 0000
    out ddrc, r16 ;set all c pins as input
    ldi r16, 0xFF ; set r16 = 1111 1111
    out ddrd, r16 ;set all d pins as output
    out ddrb, r16 ;set all b pins as output

    ldi r16, HIGH(RAMEND)
    out SPH, r16
    ldi r16, LOW(RAMEND)
    out SPL, r16



prog:
    ;----------------initialise adc

    sbi PORTD,5
setADC:

    lds r16,0x00
    STS ADCSRA,R16

    ldi r16,0xC3
    sts ADCSRA,r16
    ldi r16,0x23    ;the 2 sets the bits to be left justified
    sts admux,r16

keepPolling:
    lds R16,ADCSRA
    sbrs R16,4 ;wait for conversion to complete, when conversion is complete the 4th bit in the ADCSRA is set to true therefor skipping the r jump because of sbrs
    jmp keepPolling

    lds r17,ADCL    
    lds r16,ADCH

    sbi PORTD,2
    ldi r18,2       ;r18 is used by delay- setting it to 2 doubles the delay, as opposed to if it was set to 1
    call delay
    cbi PORTD,2
    ldi r18,2
    call delay

    rjmp prog



delay:
    loop1:
        ldi r21,150
    loop2:
        ldi r22,100
    loop3:
        mov r23,r16
    loop4:
        nop
        nop
        dec r23
        brne loop4
        dec r22
        brne loop3
        dec r21
        brne loop2
    ret
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't see how the `delay` uses `r18`? There's `r16` used.

Comment: `lds r16, 0x00` is the same as `mov r16, r0` -- you should change it to `ldi r16, 0x00`. _Hint: take a look at the values, that are written to registers on reset. If you don't need to change them, don't do it._

Comment: The Code worked fine, it was my Potentiometer that wasn't working, but thank you